# how to leave cmd open after batch file executes

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am current'y taking a Java course and because of security reasons it won't let us set environment variables for the Java compiler. What we have to do all the time is open `cmd` and then put

```
set path="path_to_java"
```

This gets really annoying because when we close the command line it loses the path. I was able to create part of the .bat file but when I execute it, then it closes instantly. I know you are able to put `PAUSE` but then it won't let us insert any Java code.

Is there any way to create a .bat file and fix this problem so when I double click it creates path variable and it lets us compile Java code?

I currently only have this

```
SET PATH "path_to_compiler"
CLS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you could do. One way would be to create your batch file somewhere (e.g. in your profile folder) and make it automatically execute whenever you start a command prompt:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "%USERPROFILE%\init.cmd"
```

However, since you're not allowed to set persistent environment variables, this may be prohibited as well. In that case you could create a shortcut to your batch script on the desktop, then open its properties and change the target to something like this:

```
%COMSPEC% /k C:\path\to\your.cmd
```

`%COMSPEC%` is the CMD executable, and the option `/k` prevents it from automatically closing after the script finished.

As a side note, you may want to include the current `%PATH%` with the path to the compiler, otherwise stuff may stop working (e.g. because some command line utilities can't be found anymore):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\javac\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked for duplicates, but I'm pretty sure I've seen a question about this recently. Anyhow, you aroused my curiosity as to how to do this, so I experimented, and fortunately the first thing I tried worked.

So, basically what you should have is...

```
@echo off
::Add your code under here
set path=path_to_compiler
cls
call cmd
```

One thing I must ask, is it absolutely necessary to make the variable called "path" instead of something else? I'm asking this because `path` is an important variable that the interpreter uses to do things.

Anyway, this basically just runs your code then opens up cmd.exe within the current window.